# Python MemoryError when using long lists not occurring on Linux

Tags: python, linux, windows, python-2.7, memory-management

I've come to work with a rather big simulation code which needs to store up to `189383040` floating point numbers. I know, this is large, but there isn't much that could be done to overcome this, like only looking at a portion of them or processing them one-by-one.

I've written a short script, which reproduces the error so I could quickly test it in different environments:

```
noSnapshots = 1830
noObjects = 14784

objectsDict={}

for obj in range(0, noObjects):
    objectsDict[obj]=[[],[],[]]
    for snapshot in range(0,noSnapshots):
        objectsDict[obj][0].append([1.232143454,1.232143454,1.232143454])
        objectsDict[obj][1].append([1.232143454,1.232143454,1.232143454])
        objectsDict[obj][2].append(1.232143454)
```

It represents the structure of the actual code where some parameters (2 `lists` of length 3 each and 1 float) have to be stored for each of the `14784` objects at `1830` distinct locations. Obviously the numbers would be different each time for a different object, but in my code I just went for some randomly-typed number.

The thing, which I find not very surprising, is that it fails on Windows 7 Enterprise and Home Premium with a `MemoryError`. Even if I run the code on a machine with 16 GB of RAM it still fails, even though there's still plenty of memory left on the machine. So the first question would be: **Why does it happen so? I'd like to think that the more RAM I've got the more things I can store in the memory.**

I ran the same code on an Ubuntu 12.04 machine of my colleague (again with 16 GB of RAM) and it finished no-problem. So another thing which I'd like to know is: **Is there anything I could do to make Windows happy with this code? I.e. give my Python process more memory on heap and stack?**

Finally: **Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to store plenty of data in memory in a manner similar to the one in the example code?**

**EDIT**

After the answer I changed the code to:

```
import numpy

noSnapshots = 1830
noObjects = int(14784*1.3)

objectsDict={}

for obj in range(0, noObjects):
    objectsDict[obj]=[[],[],[]]

    objectsDict[obj][0].append(numpy.random.rand(noSnapshots,3))
    objectsDict[obj][1].append(numpy.random.rand(noSnapshots,3))
    objectsDict[obj][2].append(numpy.random.rand(noSnapshots,1))
```

and it works despite the larger amount of data, which has to be stored.

Comment: Are you using a 64-bit build of Python on Windows?

Comment: Good point. It was a 32b Windows and 64b Linux.

Comment: That limits the RAM available to Windows to 4GB.

Comment: @Max would it be possible to increase this limit when using 64b Python? Or upgrading to Python 3.X?

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke: On Windows?  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778.aspx  .  For Windows 7 on x86 (32-bit), the entire OS can access only 4 gigs of RAM.  There is no way for Python to have access to any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, every `float` is an object on the heap, with its own reference count, etc. For storing this many floats, you really ought to use a *dense* representation of lists of floats, such as `numpy`'s `ndarray`.

Also, because you are reusing the same `float` objects, you are not estimating the memory use correctly.  You have lists of references to the same single `float` object.  In a real case (where the `float`s are different) your memory use would be much higher.  You really ought to use `ndarray`.

Comment: Yes I thought about the latter point. However, it does make the program throw a `MemoryError` regardless, so I assumed it was more-or-less OK for the purpose of testing.

Comment: As for `numpy` arrays it won't be that easy because appending them isn't really an option as there isn't an easy way to do this without causing periodic memory jumps. U'll give pre-allocating a try but it may consume more memory than needed (not every object will have the maximum number of entries). But anyway, thanks a lot for help.

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke: A Python list would have the same periodic memory jumps as `ndarray`.

Comment: That I didn't know. Never had to worry about any memory management in python.

Comment: I checked pre-allocating the arrays and it seems to do the trick, even if the arrays are longer than in the example above. Thanks a lot.